# Error when trying to call c++ function from python

Tags: python, c++, dll

I am trying to write a math library in c++ for a game I made in python. I tried following the steps from answer by Florian Bosch in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python) question.

My operating system is windows 10.
Here is the code in c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct Math
{

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "hehe" << std::endl;
    }

};

extern"C"
{
    Math* newMath()
    {
        return new Math();
    }

    void math_print(Math* math)
    {
        math->print();
    }
}
```

Code in python

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./math.so')

class Math:
    def __init__(self):
        self.object = lib.newMath()

    def print(self):
        lib.print = (self.object)

math = Math()
math.print()
```

Compilation of .o and .so files

```
g++ -c -fPIC math.cpp -o math.o 
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,math.so -o math.so  math.o
```

Error message

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 1114] A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
```

Both my python interpreter and g++ compiler are 64 bits.

After n.'pronouns'm's comment about linkers, I decided to remove the `#include<iostream>` from c++ file to see what happens, and it sort of worked.
I changed the c++ code to

```
//#include <iostream>

struct Math
{

    int print()
    {
        return 5;
    }

};

extern"C"
{
    Math* newMath()
    {
        return new Math();
    }

    void math_print(Math* math)
    {
        math->print();
    }
```

and python code to

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./math.so')

class Math:
    def __init__(self):
        self.object = lib.newMath()

    def print(self):
        lib.math_print = (self.object)

math = Math()
print(math.print())
```

I would expect it to print 5, but it prints `none` and no error this time. I will also definitely need libraries in the future to access the math functions.

Comment: Linux style compilation and library naming convention followed by windows style DLL error. What system are you working on? Also, once you got it working, I think that python will interpret the pointer as integer.

Comment: @pptaszni I am working on windows 10

Comment: Uhh, fastest solution would be to use Linux :) (which you can also quickly install install inside windows). I don't remember exact steps to do it on windows, but you need to build DLL first and then load it with python cdll. Also your `print` function is wrong. Should be `lib.math_print(self.object)`

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Do you run python in the same shell you build your library?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I ran python from IDLE by pressing f5

Comment: This could be your problem, IDLE probably doesn't know where your C++ runtime libraries are. Try running python from the command line in the same shell you run g++ from.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Just tried doing that but still getting the same error. Just  to be sure, I recompiled the .o and .so files from cmd and than ran python from the same cmd window. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, this exact procedure works for me. Can you compile and run a hello world C++ program from the same cmd?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It might be my g++. I did try reinstalling it but its still not working. My g++ version is `g++ (tdm64-1) 9.2.0`. Which one are you using? Can you send a download link please. Maybe it will work with your version

Comment: I use msys2, gcc is a package in it. Have you tried to compile and run a hello world program?

Comment: Yes i have tried doing that and it works. Also,  I edited the question.

Comment: Please, for the future, before even asking a question, create a [mcve]. In particular, does it work for a single function returning a simple integer? As it stands, you now have two different questions concerning two different versions of code mixed in one, which isn't good.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It isn't really 2 different questions. I just commented out the line that was causing problems in the second example but I am still looking for a solution. But yea sure, ill be careful next time

Comment: It is likely that python cannot find libstdc++. Try adding the directory where that library is located to your PATH environment. You can also try and look at the library with a tool such as [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and see what is missing.